# @angular/http to @angular/common/http replacement for Headers, RequestOptions

Tags: angular

I am try to modify HTTP request from `@angular/http` to `@angular/common/http` but what is the replacement for the `RequestOptions` and `Headers`?

Before:

```
let reqOpt=new RequestOptions();

let headers = new Headers();
```

Now what is the replaced import for the `RequestOptions`?

I checked the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#angularhttp) but there I did not find any Angular HTTP in search.

Comment: Did you read https://angular.io/guide/http#adding-and-updating-headers?

Comment: No,thanks @jonrsharpe .i was looking for the same ref link.

Answer (score 0):

The get, post apis have an options parameter that can include headers.
For example:

```
http.get('path', {
  headers: {
    'MY-FIRST-HEADER': 'some value',
    'MY-SECOND-HEADER': 'some other value',
  }
});
```